# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: headers is not defined VueJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

1. I am using laravel application with Vuejs so I want after a certain process is completed to save the information by hitting the post method endpoint.
2. In the local environment, it's working perfectly but after I launch the application on Cpanel I am getting this error.

So please someone may help me to figure it out thanks.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("series_id", this.series.id);
formData.append("user_id", this.users);
formData.append("transaction_id", response.data.params.transactionId);
formData.append("request_id", response.data.requestId);
formData.append("amount", response.data.params.txAmount);


let url = "https://example.so/api/add-purchase";
axios.post(url, formData, headers).then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
           if (response.status == 200) {
               alert(response.data.message);
               window.location.href ="/student/courses";
            }
});
this.isLoading = false;
```

Comment: `axios.post(url, formData, headers)` ... how can this work, since headers is NOT defined anywhere? just remove `, headers` from that code

Comment: from your code, its obvious that you have defined url, formData but not header

Comment: Sorry it is but I didn't include in my question here

Comment: Could you show the whole code with the headers defined?